# How to achieve this layout in Android (studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

my name is Josh. I am trying to achieve the below layout in Android but I can't seem to split the inner layout to get the layout I want. Can someone help please.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.firstapplication.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The only problem I am having is, I can't figure out how to split the layout as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this multiple ways. I don't know the requirement for your layout but you really don't need two `LinearLayout` to solve this. However, with what you have currently all you have to do is give your first `LinearLayout` an id, and set the height to `wrap_content` like so:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

then in your second layout set the positioning to be below your first one, set the height to `wrap_content` and remove `layout_alignParentTop` otherwise your second layout will overlap to your first. So you have something like this for the second:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/LL1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

This will put the second layout underneath the first, but the sizing will vary unless the first layout is always a constant height.

If you know you always want a 70:30 ratio regardless of the first layout height, you can use `layout_weights` instead. I can add that in if that's what you're looking for instead.

To have a constant ratio, change your root layout to be `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` then set the orientation to be vertical and a `weightSum` to 1.

Then set your first `LinearLayout` to be a `layout_weight` of 0.7 and your second `LinearLayout` to be a `layout_weight` of 0.3. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"></LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, yes I am looking for around 70:30 / 80:20 ratio for the 2 layouts

Comment: @JoshDeo, check out the second part of my answer.

Comment: Yes this is what I want, one problem when I put in a EditText in layout 2, it either goes above the layout or inside and stretches the layout. Is it possbile to make the edittext to take full width and height of layout but leave the weight to 0.3 without stretching,

Comment: @JoshDeo, of course. Set the `width` and `height` attributes of `EditText` to be `match_parent`. I'm not sure what you mean by "without stretching" though. Are you talking about the layout or the `EditText`?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve a 70:30 split between an image and EditText using constraint layout?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, set your inner layouts to both have a `height` of `0dp` instead of `wrap_content` this will enforce the heights never change.

Comment: When I place a EditText inside layout 2  it makes the the layout 2 look bigger then .03 weight

Comment: Read my comment right above yours, and check my code. It should do what you want.

Comment: Do you mean the height of the layout itself or the item I am placing inside the layout like EditText.

Comment: I made the change in my code. You can see that I set it to the inner layouts. Then you can set your `EditText` to be whatever height you want and it will always be constrained to the layout it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Set the LinearLayout's height parameters accordingly to achieve the desired ratio between two layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="**XYZ dp**"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

Comment: Hi, please correct me if I am wrong do you mean something like android:layout_height="100 dp". Wouldn't this be hard coding?

Comment: Yes, it would. You need your Height to be dynamical? I didn't know that. But if you want to have it like that all the time, it is OK if it's hard-coded.